# Groovy: Find duplicates in Multiple arrays

Tags: groovy

I have three arrays as below and need to find the maching/duplicate in all of these

```
`def Ids_AS =[04-04350, 21-005676, REGU-132644681]
def Ids_AO= [ 04-04350, 04-04356, REGU-132644681]
def Ids_AV= [ 04-04350, AB-132644681, REGU-132644681]`
println(IdsResultMissingOnSolrOutPut_AS.intersect(IdsResultMissingOnSolrOutPut_AV))
```

I used intersect but it is getting applies on 2 arrays/list only

Another Case: Need to handle empty array like below and it should match the rest of remaining instead of returning null or error

```
`def Ids_AS =[04-04350, 21-005676, REGU-132644681]
def Ids_AO= [ 04-04350, 04-04356, REGU-132644681]
def Ids_AV= []`
```

is there way to find duplicates on multiple arrays? Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do the intersection for the third array

```
def duplicates = Ids_AS.intersect(Ids_AO).intersect(Ids_AV)
```

If you want to get clever, and you have many, you can make a list of your lists, and then use `inject` (fold) to intersect them all against each other

```
def all = [Ids_AS, Ids_AO, Ids_AV]

def duplicates = all.inject { a, b -> a.intersect(b) }
```

Both methods will result in

```
['04-04350', 'REGU-132644681']
```

For the second question, sort the list of lists so the longest one is first, and then ignore empty lists

```
def duplicates = all.sort { -it.size() }.inject { a, b -> b.empty ? a : a.intersect(b) }
```

Comment: Bundle of thanks, This worked for me